# How to Silence SQLite3 logger in Sinatra with Active Record?

Tags: activerecord, logging, rspec, sqlite, sinatra

The guard output window fills up with

```
D, [2012-11-19T18:36:30.391459 #53057] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
D, [2012-11-19T18:36:30.392668 #53057] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "foo" ("created_at", "id", "foo", "foo", "updated_at", "value") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", 2012-11-19 18:36:30 -0800], ["id", 4], ["bar", 2], ["foo", 12], ["updated_at", 2012-11-19 18:36:30 -0800], ["value", true]]
D, [2012-11-19T18:36:30.393572 #53057] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  commit transaction
```

How to turn off this output?

I tried `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil`, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Using `sinatra-activerecord`, `rspec` and `guard`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = 1
```

Any value of 1 or greater works. I guess it may work for other databases as well.

[Reference](http://blog.habanerohq.com/post/16800611137/selectively-silence-activerecord-logging)